# NullPointer while using FTP connection

Tags: java, ftp

I'm using `FTPClient` to access ftp server. And this is how I do:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {
            String SERVER = "10.67.192.18";
            String USER = "user";
            String PASS = "pass";
            String DIR = "/reports/ClientSessions/";
            ftpClient.connect(SERVER, 21);
            ftpClient.login(USER, PASS);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftpClient.setFileType(org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            InputStream io1 = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(DIR + "filename1.csv");
            System.out.println(io1);
            io1.close();
            InputStream io2 = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(DIR + "filename1.csv");
            System.out.println(io2);
            io2.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {

                ftpClient.logout();
                ftpClient.disconnect();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The second `InputStream` is null. If I'll comment first `InputStream`, code will be executed well. What is wrong?

Comment: Looks like the file is not there or can not read. See the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFileStream(java.lang.String))

Comment: Have you took a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257639/android-ftpclient-retrievefilestream-always-returns-null?

Comment: `451 Requested action aborted. Local error in processing`

Comment: I would suspect that when you `close()` your first InputStream, you are also closing the underlying connection stuff that FTPClient is using.  Therefore, your second InputStream has nothing to point to.  If you need to pull down multiple files, either don't close the stream immediately, or re-connect for each file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in official documentation here: [http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFileStream(java.lang.String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFileStream%28java.lang.String%29) is said the `null` is returned if no file was found.
Also  The `InputStream` itself will take care of closing the parent data connection socket upon being closed. So after closing the first `InputStream`  connection socket are closed too. Close you streams in `finally` block only.

Answer (score 1):

Does it happen every time? According to Wikipedia's [List of FTP Return Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes), "4xx is a Transient Negative Completion reply ... The command was not accepted and the requested action did not take place, but the error condition is temporary and the action may be requested again."

Also, is csv considered a binary? Try setting the type to `FTP.ASCII_FILE_TYPE`.

According to the [JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#retrieveFileStream%28java.lang.String%29) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507660/problem-with-ftpclient-class-in-java) you are missing a step.

> To finalize the file transfer you must call **completePendingCommand** and check its return value to verify success.

Comment: Nope. Still NullPointer.